# Using Bash, how can I delete all the desktop.ini in my external drive folder tree?

Tags: linux, bash, rm

I am using my external HDD to store my music, and now I've installed Linux on my PC.

I would like to erase all the `desktop.ini` files in the thousand nested folders on the HDD, how can I accomplish this using only bash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably possible to do with just bash, but there's actually quite possibly a better option to do it using `find`.

Assuming you have write permission to the directories in question, it would be as simple as:

```
find /media/external-music-store -iname desktop.ini -delete
```

To test it first (strongly recommended), try something like this:

```
find /media/external-music-store -iname desktop.ini -print | less
```

which will give you a scrollable list of all files it would delete. (To exit `less`, press <kbd>q</kbd>; to scroll up and down, use the arrow keys.)

I am pretty sure that `find` is included in the standard install with most Linux distributions, and certainly most desktop-oriented ones. Debian packages it as `findutils` which is an `essential` and `required` package.

Using `-iname` causes case insensitive matching on the file name, matching Windows' semantics. Its counterpart `-name` uses case sensitive matching (which is the normal mode of operation on Unix-like systems, including Linux).

Comment: Thank you, a very complete answer! i've used the same command to erase also all the AlbumArt* file in the tree, almost unuseful under a linux environement.

Comment: @AlfaTaurus Glad I was able to help. Welcome to SuperUser and Stack Exchange.